# SharePoint Calendar: Some features required for enhanced functionality

Tags: calendar

I need following features for SharePoint default Calendar

1. Creating task automatically from calendar on particular date.
2. Sharing calendar in sharepoint

Is it possible?

Can someone list the process on how to do it?

-saumil

ps I use WSS 3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first feature can be done with a (e.g. SharePoint Designer) Workflow.
And you can share the calender with other people giving them the needed permissions on that list (here: calender). In addition you can connect it with Outlook.